# Older version of gfortran doesn't get installed despite removal newer version

Tags: macos

I installed gfortran v6.3.0 using installer, and needed to go back to 4.9.2.
I removed gfortran using `sudo rm -r /usr/local/gfortran /usr/local/bin/gfortran`, but when I try to install v4.9.2 using a disk image, it says a newer version already exists.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did installer for v6,3 have an uninstaller with it?

Comment: @john no, it did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apps such as [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to fully uninstall apps.

In your case there are likely files left on your computer for v6.3.0 and using App Cleaner will remove these additional files.

You can do this manually by finding and deleting the .plist and .bom files associated with gfortran. Type 'locate gfortran' in a terminal window will find the path names to these files.

Comment: It doesn't work in that case because gfortran is a compiler, and doesn't show up in the Applications list.

Comment: Did you try to force the app to look for gfortran?  As an alternative, you can type 'locate gfortran' from the terminal and find these files yourself. I'm just not positive about which ones to delete.  There should be some files with extension 'plist'. I do know those have to be deleted.

Comment: I tried to make it look for gfortran, it doesn't show up. However, I checked for gfortran plist files, found them as well as gfortran bom files. This resolved the error. Thanks a lot for your insightful comments! Could you please add the removal of plist and bom files in your answer so as to cover this case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you resolved your problem.